# registering file types supported by an application to open files from other apps

Tags: ios, xcode, uidocumentinteraction

I want my app to be able to copy files (images, videos, etc..) from other applications throughout iOS, after looking through apples documentation and some online sources I still haven't been able to get it to work. I have attached an image of what my info plist looks like.

[image]

here is the plist code for that section:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>All Files</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
            <string>public.content</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: When you say 'it doesn't work' do you get an error, or what does or doesn't happen?

Comment: I mean that I can't find my application when I click on the share button from other applications like the photos app for example. @DJohnson

Comment: The Photos app doesn't show any other apps unless they implement a specific kind of app extension. So that's a bad example to test if your setup is working or not.

Comment: then what is the code above supposed to do ?

Comment: note that I have also implemented this function  application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool in my appdelegate

Comment: But what code you actually wrote for your app?  You're asking what that code should be doing, therefore i assume that it is not your code.

Comment: @rmaddy Can you be more precise about "...unless they implement a specific kind of app extension" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Registering file types will help if you want iOS to open your app when someone clicks an email attachment with a file extension which you are claiming for your app.

But I think what you want is to be able to share a file from another app to your app. You need to [create an app extension of type "Share"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH12-SW1).

Comment: If I want associate a file extension of type `.exa` to my app does that mean I have to provide that info in the `LSItemContentTypes` key; `com.example.exa`, `*.exa`, `com.MYCFBundleName.exa`, `CFBundleIdentifier.exa`? I am trying to follow this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html